# Can't apply a value to a list

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I'm trying to store the emails gotten from certain links. I encounter two problems. The first one is that for some reason the element email stores two of the same type of item. And the second problem is that the if statement detects that email has a value but it doesn't store it in the emails list. Thank you for helping out!

```
emails = []
comment = []

with open('comment.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
        currentPlace = line[:-1]
        comment.append(currentPlace)

print(emails)

i = 0
while i < len(comment) :
    url = str(comment[i]) + '/about'

    print("Crawling URL %s" % url)
    response = requests.get(url)

    email = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", response.text, re.I)

    print(email)

    if email:
        emails.append(email)

    email.clear()

    i += 1
    time.sleep(0.2)

print(emails)
```

Output:

```
[]
Crawling URL ...
['email@gmail.com', 'email@gmail.com']
Crawling URL ...
[]
Crawling URL ...
['email@yahoo.com', 'email@yahoo.com']
Crawling URL ...
[]
Crawling URL ...
[]
[[], []]
```

old code outputs correctly:

```
emails = set()
print("Crawling URL %s" % starting_url)

response = requests.get(starting_url)

new_emails = set(re.findall(r"[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+", response.text, re.I))
emails.update(new_emails)
print(emails)
# create a beutiful soup for the html document
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Is it an error? the response seems to include that email twice in its content

Comment: No errors. The site only contains one email. The old code works perfectly fine and only outputs one email. But for some reason the new code output two emails

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall this returns the list of all matches of your regular expression. So the regular expression is finding 2 matches for your email regexp.

You then do `emails.append(email)`. But `email` is itself a list of emails. So your `emails` list ends up looking like `[["1@1.com","1@1.com"], ["2@2.com","2@2.com"], ... ]`.

Comment: Yeah exactly. But the weird thing is that the site only contains one email. I converted the old code (which only returned one email from the re.findAll). But the other problem is that when I try to print the email list it doesn't contain any values. Old code in Edit

Comment: The old code uses `new_emails = set(re.findall(...`. A set cannot contain duplicate values so the re probably found 2 copies of the same email but the set will only store that email once. You then do `emails.update(new_emails)` which again updates the `emails` set with extra values, and again duplicates will be discarded/ignored.

Comment: You use `email.clear()`. So you add the 2-item `email` list into the `emails` list-of-lists, but you then clear the email list, so it clears it from the inside of `emails` too.